# LibGdx avoid TouchUp after screen change

Tags: java, android, libgdx

Upon `touchDown()` I call `game.setScreen(new ScreenClass(this));`

This works great but when it gets to the new screen and I release my mouse (or lift my finger) the new screen is firing a `touchUp()` event. Is there a way to prevent this first `touchUp` from getting recorded ?

Comment: This might be an obvious question but have you tried moving your logic into the touchUP instead of the touch down, does it have to be on the touch down?

Comment: I did mention this below. It may be the best option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply add a flag on the second screen to ignore the first touchup event.

```
private boolean isFirstTouchUp = true;
```

In the touchup event, add this code,

```
if(isFirstTouchUp){
 isFirstTouchUp = false;
}else{
 // Do you touchup event here,
}
```

Hope I can help you :D

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I was wondering if there is something built into LibGDX that I missed to handle this. Your solution is a great work around.

Comment: As I know there isnt any buildin function :D Good luck

Comment: Another suggestion I have received is to do the screen change on touchUp...this would also solve the problem. I am using your idea. Thanks

Comment: Using `touchUp()` would be a better idea because generally an action is performed upon **click** event, which is a `touchDown()` followed by a `touchUp()`.